# Spring Integration - Customize ObjectMapper used by WebFlux OutboundGateway

Tags: spring-integration

How do we customize the Jackson `ObjectMapper` used by WebFlux OutboundGateway? The normal customization done via `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` or `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` is NOT respected.

Without this customization, `LocalDate` is serialized as `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`. Sample output - [2022-10-20] and there is NO way to customize the format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you really talk about Spring Boot auto-configuration which is applied to the `WebFlux` instance. Consider to use an overloaded `WebFlux.outboundGateway(String uri, WebClient webClient)` to be able to auto-wire a `WebClient.Builder` which might be already configured with the mentioned customized `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Thanks, had to configure the customized `ObjectMapper` in the already customized `WebClient` bean with SSL, etc and it did the job !!

Answer (score 0):

Registering a bean of type `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule` will automatically be used by the pre-configured `ObjectMapper` bean. In `SimpleModule`, it is possible to register custom serialization and deserialization specifications.

To put that into code, a very simple solution would be the following:

```java
@Bean
public SimpleModule odtModule() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();

    JsonSerializer<LocalDate> serializer = new JsonSerializer<>() {
        @Override
        public void serialize(LocalDate odt, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
            String formatted = odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
            jgen.writeString(formatted);
        }
    };
    JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>() {
        @Override
        public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
            return LocalDate.parse(jsonParser.getValueAsString());
        }
    };

    module.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, serializer);
    module.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, deserializer);

    return module;
}
```

Note that using lambdas for the implementations has sometimes resulted in weird behaviors for me, so I tend not to do that.

Comment: Sorry, it still did not work with Spring Integration !! I am more surprised why `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` or `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` was not respected, which is the usual way in Spring Web / MVC / WebFlux